# minimum set of module/methods in jquery code for selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading jquery code now.
I found the following methods are suitable for cross platform programming.
(desktop, web browser and mobile app)

```
$(selector)
$.ajax()     <----------I am not sure if this is veryuseful
$(selector).find()
$(selector).bind()
$(selector).unbind()
$(selector).delegate()
$(selector).remove()
$(selector).attr()
$(selector).html()
```

I mean that I prefer the javascript native code to process logic business except some selector/dom methods. This means that I even can use the same logic code in QT/QML.

Is there is a minimum set of module/methods for the function above?

Comment: [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you simply want a light-weight version of jQuery. While you may only want to use the above functions, chopping down jQuery won't give a massive boost if that is what you are looking for. Of course, using the native DOM functions is MUCH faster, but, you are free to use both in conjunction as well.

There is Zepto (http://zeptojs.com/) which will be able to do all of the functions you requested.

In addition, http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/ can be used to build a custom jQuery build and you can remove the 'css', 'ajax', and 'effect' to bring down the size of the package while retaining the core features